# Nil for MR_inContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

according to this tutorial (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Working-with-Managed-Object-Contexts.md) I tried to find my device and update it.

```
Person *person = ...;

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){

  Person *localPerson = [person MR_inContext:localContext];
  localPerson.firstName = @"John";
  localPerson.lastName = @"Appleseed";

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

  self.everyoneInTheDepartment = [Person findAll];

}];
```

So I made:

```
CDDevice *device = [CDDevice MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"deviceName"
                       withValue:uniqueName];
```

Which found my device.  After few IF statements where i test if device have proper session and authorization code I want to update it.

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
                         CDDevice * localDevice = [device MR_inContext:localContext];
                         [localDevice updateFromDictionary:messageDictionary];
                 } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                         NET_LOG(@"Updating current device %@", device);
                 }];
```

But all the time my localDevice is nil. Is it because MR_findFirstByAttribute running in different context? What is correct way to update my device?

All of this happing on my custom serial queue, because this code is in network part of project. (Receviver method with GCDAsyncUdpSocket )

Comment: Hi. It's looks like the `device` was inserted to the context but not saved (has a temporary `ObjectID`). Can you debug the method `MR_inContext:` ?

Comment: You are almost right. But thanks for help! I created device in wrong context and that was the reason why i could not retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you save your data before retrieving it in the background context.